# Doubled relationship in GraphQL

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-amplify, multiplayer, aws-appsync

I'm developing Tic Tac Toe game with multiplayer as my student project. I'm using AWS AppSync (GraphQL). I have 3 types in my schema: Board, Move and User. Two users must be connected to the Board to play a game. How can I do that? Currently, I have:

```
type Board @model {
    id: ID!
    user1Id: User @connection (name:"boards")
    user2Id: User @connection (name:"boards")
    winner: String
    turn: String
    moves:[Move] @connection (name:"moves")
}


type Move @model {
    id: ID!
    userId: User @connection (name:"plays")
    BoardId: Board @connection (name:"moves")
    position: Int
    turn: String
}

type User @model {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    score: Int
    ruchy: [Move] @connection (name:"plays")
    boards: [Board] @connection (name: "boards")
}
```

but I have an error:

> Reason: Reason: One or more parameter values were invalid: Some AttributeDefinitions are not used. AttributeDefinitions: [boardUs
>   er2IdId, boardUser1IdId, id], keys used: [boardUser1IdId, id] (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: V
>   alidationException; Request ID: 5VDI6AV22119I15OJDNGA2CJUBVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG)

What should I do to repair that and add two users to one board?